# Hints for evaluating $ \lim_{y \to +\infty}y \int_0^{+\infty}{e^{-x^2}\sin(2xy) dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, improper-integrals

Please give me some hints for this limit.

$ \lim_{y \to +\infty} y\int_0^{+\infty}{e^{-x^2}\sin(2xy) dx}$

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Riemann's—Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It might be helpful to provide any attempts on the question.

Comment: @ClementC.: Riemann-Lebesgue lemma does not yield any result directly, since the $y$ counteracts the vanishing integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dIntegrate by parts twice.
\begin{align}
I &:=y\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\sin(2xy) dx  \\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x^2}d\cos(2xy) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}-\int_{x=0}^\infty \cos(2xy)xe^{-x^2}dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2y}\int_{x=0}^\infty xe^{-x^2}d\sin(2xy)  \\
&= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2y}\int_{x=0}^\infty \sin(2xy)(1-2x^2)e^{-x^2} dx \tag{1}
\end{align}
We see that 
$$\bigg|\int_{x=0}^\infty \sin(2xy)(1-2x^2)e^{-x^2} dx\bigg|<\int_{x=0}^\infty (1-2x^2)e^{-x^2} dx,$$
as $|\sin(u)|\le 1$. The right hand side is convergent, so the left hand side is bounded (actually convergent by examining the right tail integrals) uniformly for all $y$.

Therefore the second term of Eq. (1) vanishes as $y\to\infty$ and 
$$I=\frac{1}{2}+\mathcal O\Big(\frac{1}{y}\Big).$$

Comment: Riemann Lebesgue polishes it off at line 2 if you like.

Comment: @zhw: I am fully aware of Riemann Lebesgue, but I would like to use as little advanced machinery as possible.